# Laravel relación varias tablas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy empezando con laravel y no me aclaro mucho en cuanto a hacer consultas complejas. Estoy intentando hacer una consulta a dos tablas: la tabla bajos y la tabla marcas. En la tabla bajos tengo el id_marca que es por donde los relaciono. Lo que quiero es mostrar la marca que tiene cada bajo, además de otros campos del bajo

Dentro de Controlador_panel_bajos tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde muestro el listado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí está el modelo Bajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago un dd($bajos) me muestra los resultado que quiero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al hacer la llamada me da este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no sé por donde tirar.

Comment: ¿ya fue solucionado?

Comment: Si, al final hice esta consulta $bajos = Bajo::join('marcas','bajos.id_marca','=','marcas.id')
   ->select('bajos.id','bajo','marca','bajos.publicado','bajos.portada','bajos.url')
   ->orderBy('bajo', 'asc')
   ->get();

Comment: eso es incorrecto, no estás aprovechando la potencia de eloquent y las relaciones.

Answer (score 0):

El error te está diciendo que la propiedad mostrar_marca no existe. Esto es porque tu consulta no devuelve ninguna propiedad que se llame mostrar marca. El objeto $bajos solo puede mostrar lo que devuelve tu consulta.

El código correcto sería.

```
<span>$bajos->marca</span>
```

Recuerda no darle espacio entre el objeto y ->.

Comment: Esto es incorrecto, el OP intenta utilizar una relación que está definida en el modelo, la idea es enseñarle a utilizar las relaciones en Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta que realizas no es compleja como tal, tan solo necesitas usar Eager Loading para cargar la relación mostrar_marca y ordenar los resultados.

Algo así debería funcionar en el controlador:

```
$bajos = Bajo::with('mostrar_marca')->orderBy('bajo', 'asc')->get();
```

como puedes ver, no necesitas definir los join ni similares, Eloquent y sus relaciones lo hacen por ti.

Si la relación existe o si hay registros en la tabla marcas, puedes usar el código que muestras en la vista.

```
{{ $bajos->mostrar_marca->marca }}
```

Si usas Laravel 5.5, puedes usar un sencillo helper para evitar errores en caso que no hayan modelos relacionados:

```
{{ optional($bajos->mostrar_marca)->marca }}
```

Aquí está la documentación relacionada:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional

Comment: He hecho una prueba y sale este error:
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Poniendo un return en el modelo
 public function mostrar_marca(){
  return $this -> belongsTo('App\Marca','id');
 }

Sigue dando el mismo mensaje de error. ¿Tengo que definir foreign keys en las tablas?

Comment: Lo correcto es definir foreign keys si estás haciendo una relación entre dos tablas. Por lo que veo el foreign Key sería id_marca, y ese debería ser el segundo parámetro que pasas a belongsTo

Comment: He añadido el foreign_key en la tabla bajos y he pasado el id_marca como segundo parámetro en el belongTo. Si hago un dd($bajos) sale el listado en json de los datos que busco pero al llamar la vista sigue dando el error "Property [mostrar_marca] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: agregaste lo que te dije en la vista? lo de optional

Comment: Si, lo he añadido. De todas formas uso la versión 5.4 de laravel

Comment: optional no existe en 5.4. En cuanto a la relación, al hacer el dd aparece mostrar_marca en las relaciones? deberías llamar el método de la relación en camelcase

Comment: Si, aparece como relations. Además si hago return de $bajos aparece la marca que tiene relacionada

Comment: puedes agregar dicho resultado a la pregunta? quiero ver como aparece

Comment: Vale, hemos avanzado. Estaba llamando a $bajos en lugar de $bajo en la vista. Ahora me sale otro mensaje: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: agrega la información que te solicité

Answer (score 0):

Ya que no has aceptado una respuesta te comento rapido que indica ese error.
Todo lo hiciste bien pero tuviste un error en:

```
{{ $bajos->mostrar_marca->marca }}
```

El error indica que no existe esa propiedad en la instancia seleccionada, sucede porque iteraste con foreach pero aún así pediste la propiedad a `$bajos` y no a `$bajo`

`$bajos` es una coleccion de 55 items

Al hacer el `@foreach($bajos as $bajo)` indicas que recorrerás la colección `$bajos` llamando a cada elemento `$bajo`

`$bajo` es cada item perteneciente a la colección `$bajos`